# Chatbot replies not displayed on web page, only in terminal

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

Description:
I have developed a chatbot using Flask and JavaScript. While the chatbot works correctly in my terminal, I'm encountering an issue when I access it through a web page. Upon running python3 app.py and navigating to "http://127.0.0.1:5001", the chatbot replies are not displayed on the web page. Strangely, when I send a message, my input appears in the chatbox, but the chatbot's response remains invisible. Consequently, the chatbot only seems to function when I run it on my terminal on VS Code.

Below is the code for my app.js file:

```
class Chatbox {
  constructor() {
    this.args = {
      openButton: document.querySelector(".chatbox__button"),
      sendButton: document.querySelector(".send__button"),
    };

    this.state = false;
    this.messages = [];
  }

  toggleState(chatBox) {
    chatBox.classList.toggle("chatbox--active");
  }

  onSendButton(chatBox) {
    var textField = chatBox.querySelector("input");
    let text1 = textField.value;
    if (text1 === "") {
      return;
    }

    let msg1 = { name: "User", message: text1 };
    this.messages.push(msg1);

    fetch($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/predict", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: text1 }),
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((r) => {
        let msg2 = { name: "Sam", message: r.answer };
        this.messages.push(msg2);
        this.updateChatText(chatBox);
        textField.value = "";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        this.updateChatText(chatBox);
        textField.value = "";
      });
  }

  updateChatText(chatBox) {
    var html = "";
    this.messages
      .slice()
      .reverse()
      .forEach(function (item, index) {
        if (item.name === "Sam") {
          html +=
            '<div class="messages__item messages__item--visitor">' +
            item.message +
            "</div>";
        } else {
          html +=
            '<div class="messages__item messages__item--operator">' +
            item.message +
            "</div>";
        }
      });

    const chatMessage = chatBox.querySelector(".chatbox__messages");
    chatMessage.innerHTML = html;
  }

  display() {
    const { openButton, sendButton } = this.args;
    const chatBox = document.querySelector(".chatbox__support");

    openButton.addEventListener("click", () => this.toggleState(chatBox));

    sendButton.addEventListener("click", () => this.onSendButton(chatBox));

    const inputNode = chatBox.querySelector("input");
    inputNode.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
        this.onSendButton(chatBox);
      }
    });
  }
}

const chatbox = new Chatbox();
chatbox.display();
```

Furthermore, here's the HTML code in my base.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Chatbot</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="chatbox">
        <div class="chatbox__support">
          <div class="chatbox__header">
            <div class="chatbox__image--header">
              <img
                src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/circled-user-female-skin-type-5--v1.png"
                alt="image"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="chatbox__content--header">
              <h4 class="chatbox__heading--header">Chat support</h4>
              <p class="chatbox__description--header">
                Hi. My name is Sam. How can I help you?
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="chatbox__messages">
            <div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="chatbox__footer">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Write a message..." />
            <button class="chatbox__send--footer send__button">Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chatbox__button">
          <button>
            <img
              src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/chatbox-icon.svg') }}"
            />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var $SCRIPT_ROOT = "{{ request.script_root|safe }};";
    </script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{{ url_for('static', filename='app.js') }}"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and CSS code for style.css:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

*,
html {
  --primaryGradient: linear-gradient(93.12deg, #581b98 0.52%, #9c1de7 100%);
  --secondaryGradient: linear-gradient(
    268.91deg,
    #581b98 -2.14%,
    #9c1de7 99.69%
  );
  --primaryBoxShadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  --secondaryBoxShadow: 0px -10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  --primary: #581b98;
}

/* CHATBOX
=============== */
.chatbox {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
}

/* CONTENT IS CLOSE */
.chatbox__support {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #eee;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  z-index: -123456;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/* CONTENT ISOPEN */
.chatbox--active {
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  z-index: 123456;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* BUTTON */
.chatbox__button {
  text-align: right;
}

.send__button {
  padding: 6px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* HEADER */
.chatbox__header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: orange;
}

/* MESSAGES */
.chatbox__messages {
  margin-top: auto;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.messages__item {
  background: orange;
  max-width: 60.6%;
  width: fit-content;
}

.messages__item--operator {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.messages__item--visitor {
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* FOOTER */
.chatbox__footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}

.chatbox__support {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  height: 450px;
  width: 350px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

/* HEADER */
.chatbox__header {
  background: var(--primaryGradient);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: var(--primaryBoxShadow);
}

.chatbox__image--header {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.chatbox__heading--header {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: white;
}

.chatbox__description--header {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: white;
}

/* Messages */
.chatbox__messages {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.messages__item {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  max-width: 70%;
}

.messages__item--visitor,
.messages__item--typing {
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.messages__item--operator {
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  background: var(--primary);
  color: white;
}

/* FOOTER */
.chatbox__footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background: var(--secondaryGradient);
  box-shadow: var(--secondaryBoxShadow);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.chatbox__footer input {
  width: 80%;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

.chatbox__send--footer {
  color: white;
}

.chatbox__button button,
.chatbox__button button:focus,
.chatbox__button button:visited {
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

and here's app.py to run the application:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

from chat import get_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.get("/")
def index_get():
    return render_template("base.html")

@app.post("/predict")                   
def predict():
   text = request.get_json().get("message")
   # TO-DO: check if text is valid
   response = get_response(text)
   message = {"answer": response}
   return jsonify(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5001)
```

and here's chat.py:

```
import random
import json


import torch

from model import NeuralNet
from nltk_utils import bag_of_words, tokenize

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

with open('intents.json', 'r') as json_data:
    intents = json.load(json_data)

FILE = "data.pth"
data = torch.load(FILE)

input_size = data["input_size"]
hidden_size = data["hidden_size"]
output_size = data["output_size"]
all_words = data['all_words']
tags = data['tags']
model_state = data["model_state"]

model = NeuralNet(input_size, hidden_size, output_size).to(device)
model.load_state_dict(model_state)
model.eval()

bot_name = "Sam"

def get_response(msg):
    sentence = tokenize(msg)
    X = bag_of_words(sentence, all_words)
    X = X.reshape(1, X.shape[0])
    X = torch.from_numpy(X).to(device)

    output = model(X)
    _, predicted = torch.max(output, dim=1)

    tag = tags[predicted.item()]

    probs = torch.softmax(output, dim=1)
    prob = probs[0][predicted.item()]
    if prob.item() > 0.75:
        for intent in intents['intents']:
            if tag == intent["tag"]:
                return random.choice(intent['responses'])
    
    return "I do not understand..."


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Let's chat! (type 'quit' to exit)")
    while True:
        # sentence = "do you use credit cards?"
        sentence = input("You: ")
        if sentence == "quit":
            break

        resp = 'hello'
        print(resp)
```

I have thoroughly inspected my JavaScript code and the HTML structure, but I couldn't find any issues. The code responsible for updating the chatbox seems to be functioning correctly, yet the chatbot's replies don't appear on the web page.

I suspect the issue might be related to the integration between Flask and JavaScript. The Flask server receives the user's input, processes it, and returns a response, but for some reason, the response is not being displayed in the chatbox on the web page.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!